# git remote update not working on some mirror ([New Branch]?

Tags: git, git-clone

I am attempting to keep an entire backup of all my organization repositories.

To accomplish that, I am using github API to get the repositories url, for which I create a local folder and initiate a clone using `git clone clone_url --mirror`.

From there, every x hours, I iterate through the repositories that have an older Updated_at value than my last run date and do a `git remote update`on repositories with changes.

It work for most, but one in particular is giving me the following message: `*[new branch]            BUGFIX/BranchName -> BUGFIX/BranchName`

How do I complete the update so my local copy matches the remote one ?